# pebble-app.js randomly fails to start

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

Some times my pebble app fails to launch and I see the following print in the logs:

```
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: {'runhost client uuid' = 625fe469-ed20-48a7-a786-19a37200cad2}:{'webapp uuid' = 9f1e3aed-98f8-41ec-9bff-2c15fa4f3c24}: ++_JS_LIFECYCLE_++:LAUNCH-FAIL:READY-TIMEOUT
```

This happens randomly. Can some one please shed some light on why this is happening and how to fix it. My guess is that this happens because the my watch app fails to communicate with Pebble Android app but I have no idea how to confirm or fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The `onReady` function must return under a few seconds or the Pebble application will consider that it failed and will kill it. Maybe you are doing too many things in your `ready` event handler? Or you have an error in your code?

Try printing a message at the end of your `ready` event handler to see if it appears. If it does not, look at the code above to figure out what is going on.

If you have long running tasks, a very easy way to run them without delaying the `ready` event is to use `setDelay(function() { /* your code */ }, 0);`.

Comment: But the app works fine most of the time? Also I have seen people having the same problem with very simple hello world type apps.